# numpy plt.contour from matrix

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I am wondering if anyone could fill in the code for how to create a mesh grid in order to generate a contour plot?
The imported txt file is a matrix of numbers with value 0-255. I can use the following code to print the image, as such, but can't get the mesh grid set up to get a contour line plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matrix = np.loadtxt('matrix.txt')
print (matrix)

#how do I make the mesh grid here?

plt.contour(matrix)
plt.show()
```

EDIT:
Apologies I see this is similar, but utilising the former thread for the meshgrid .... they use the function 'arange'?

```
n = 12150715

x = arange (n)
y = arange (n)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
plt.contour(X, Y, matrix)

plt.contour(matrix)
plt.show()
```

I still get errors though which I don't get if I # out the parts above plt.

" File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('/myfiles/testing.py', wdir='/Volumes/.../Python')

File "/Users/ME/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "/Users/ME/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "testing.py", line 25, in 
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

File "/Users/ME/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 4684, in meshgrid
    output = [x.copy() for x in output]

File "/Users/ME/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 4684, in 
    output = [x.copy() for x in output]

MemoryError"

Comment: what did you try? have you searched stackoverflow for similar questions?

Comment: Hi, thanks, apologies I have looked into the similar question. I've edited the post to show my equivalent, but the function arange is not valid? I was expecting a solution to involve linspace perhaps?

Comment: `arange` is from numpy like `meshgrid`, call it via `np.arange` (if you see at the linked duplicate, they suppress the `np.` before both of them - assuming you imported both like `from numpy import arange, meshgrid` or similar)

Comment: thanks that makes sense apologies I hadn't read into that, I'm still getting some errors though if I include the mesh grid parts. (included in post now)

Answer (score 0):

If `n=12150715` (from where did you invent that number?) then an array with n**2 elements will not fit into your memory any more. Apart it wouldn't make sense to visualize such a huge array anyways.

Of course `x` and `y` need to coincide with the number of columns and rows of the matrix.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matrix = np.loadtxt('matrix.txt')

x = arange (matrix.shape[1])
y = arange (matrix.shape[0])
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
plt.contour(X, Y, matrix)

plt.show()
```

Comment: ok brilliant thanks for your help; this all makes sense.

my memory issue was (admittedly maybe I've invented this) that my original image was 4057 x 2995   (of which these have a value between 0-255)

(apologies for needy noob thing here, but thanks again this is much appreciated: time issues!)